# How to sort in LINQ If Join other database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sorting, join

### Sort in LINQ

I have 2 database CustomerEntities and BillEntities
I want to get CustomerName from CustomerEntities and sort it but it have no data and I want .ToList() just once time because it slow if used many .ToList()

```
using (var db1 = new CustomerEntities())
 {  using (var db2 = new BillEntities())
   {
   var CustomerData = db1.Customer.Select(s=> new{s.CustomerCode,s.CustomerName}).ToList();
   var BillData = (from t1 in db2.Bill
                  select new {
                    BillCode = t1.Billcode,
                    CustomerCode = t1.Customer,
                    CustomerName = ""; //have no data
                  });
   }
   if(sorting.status==true)
   {
    BillData= BillData.OrderBy(o=>o.CustomerName); //can't sort because CustomerName have no data
   }
   var data = BillData .Skip(sorting.start).Take(sorting.length).ToList(); // I want .ToList() just once time because it slow if used many .ToList()
   foreach (var b in data)
   {
     var Customer = CustomerData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CustomerCode==b.CustomerCode );
     if(CustomerName>!=null)
     {
       r.CustomerName = Customer.CustomerName; //loop add data CustomerName
     }
   }
 }
```

> I have no idea to do it. Help me please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your code but what about this:

```
   var BillData = (from t1 in db2.Bill
                  select new {
                    BillCode = t1.Billcode,
                    CustomerCode = t1.Customer,
                    CustomerName = db1.Customer.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustormerCode == t1.Customer)?.CustomerName
                  });
```

Then you have objects in BillData that holds the CustomerName and you can order by that:

`BillData.OrderBy(bd => bd.CustomerName);`

Comment: error: {"The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."}

Comment: @otaroo: Strange. Is CustomerCode on Customer a value or reference type? What if you use CustomerData instead of db1.Customer to query for CustomerName? If that doesn't work, I have no idea right now.

Comment: Thank you
It work if I sort after loop foreach but it very slow when many data

Comment: @otaroo: But you should not run the foreach loop with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get CustomerName from your customer Db and sort it, this is what i would have used. I used orderByDescending but you can use OrderBy aswell.

```
      public List<Customer> getLogsByCustomerName(string customername)
      {
          using (var dbentites = new CustomerEntities())
          {
            var result = (from res in dbentites.Customer.OrderByDescending(_ => _.CustomerName)
                          where res.CustomerName == customername
                          select res).ToList();
             return result.ToList();
        }
     }
```